# icCube XMLA request documentation

Tags: soap, iccube, xmla

Is there any documentation on how to formulate a request to the XMLA?

The icCube XMLA endpoint for me is: `http://localhost:8282/icCube/xmla`

I want to make a demo call to the endpoint using postman or something similar, but I am not sure which parameters to pass in the SOAP request.

I have tried:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <x:Header>
        <urn:Session SessionId="?" mustUnderstand="?"/>
        <urn:BeginSession mustUnderstand="?"/>
        <urn:EndSession SessionId="?" mustUnderstand="?"/>
    </x:Header>
    <x:Body>
        <urn:Execute>
            <Command>
                <Statement>
                     SELECT 
                         {[Customers].[Geography].[All Regions].[North America].[Canada].[Ottawa]} on COLUMNS,
                         {[Measures].[Count]} on ROWS
                     FROM [Sales]
                </Statement>
            </Command>
            <Properties/>
        </urn:Execute>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

And I get an empty response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <Session SessionId="1hb96vaa7acol14bj97tyokd4f" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis"/>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ExecuteResponse xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
            <return>
                <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty"/>
            </return>
        </ExecuteResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Does anyone know where I can find some more information on how to make this request? The icCube documentation at http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/running_iccube/xmla.php is basically non-existent.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your XMLA request is fine, just empty, try with a valid MDX that you can validate in icCube's IDE.

Comment: This same MDX returns a non-empty result in icCube's IDE.

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding a properties tag with propertyList and catalog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the correct properties information to the soap call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <Command>
        <Statement>
           SELECT 
               {[Customers].[Geography].[All Regions].[North America].[Canada].[Ottawa]} on COLUMNS,
               {[Measures].[Count]} on ROWS
           FROM [Sales]
        </Statement>
    </Command>
    <Properties>
        <PropertyList>
            <Catalog>Sales</Catalog>
        </PropertyList>
    </Properties>
  </Execute>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The best documentation I have been able to find for the XMLA is the [XML for Analysis Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977626.aspx).